# Ansible user defined inventory variable calling

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Hello My inventory is something like this

```
host1:
  machine1 
host2:
  machine1 var=x
  machine2 var=y
```

My playbook is something like this and doesn't work

```
---
- hosts: host2
  name: gather facts from host2
  tasks: []
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - name: Run command
      command: echo"{{ hostvars['host2']['var'] }}"


   #Also, I tried this "{{ hostvars.host2.var }}"
```

I need to pass x and y in the second play and Ansible gives undefined variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ironically we had this exact [same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718577/accessing-host-variables-in-tasks-in-ansible/53719151#53719151):

It's because `host1` is not a **host** it's a **group** and thus will not be in **host**vars. If you just ask for `{{ var }}` it will have the value `x` when that task evaluates on `machine1` and `y` on `machine2`. You can, of course, ask for the value of `machine1`'s `var` while on `machine2` via `{{ hostvars["machine1"].var }}` just as you tried

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't solve the problem of calling the variable of machine1(var x) that belong to host2 from machine1 of host1. Do you happen to know a possible solution ?

Comment: Well, when I run what I said using an inventory shaped like yours, I am able to access `var` from any member of `hostvars`, whether it is a member of the `- hosts:` stanza or not; what error are you experiencing?